# Create menu locations for each category in wordpress

Tags: categories, menus, array, php

I need display a special menu in each category page in wordpress,

for example I have 3 category: horse,dog,cat

So I must have 3 menu in Menu Settings **locations** with name: horse,dog,cat

with this code in `functions.php` I get all categories name:

```
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
foreach($category_ids as $cat_id) {
  $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id);
  $arr = $cat_name;
}
```

and with this code in `functions.php` I register menu:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary' => 'Main Navigation',
  'secondary' => 'Footer Navigation',
  $arr
));
```

but it's not working and registers only last category, I think we must import `register_nav_menus`'s `array` in `foreach`, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about this wrongly, I think. The `theme_location` parameter for `wp_nav_menu()` is a *template* location - i.e. a *physical* location in the template, as defined/registered by the Theme. It's not designed for an arbitrary number of locations based on arbitrary user content.

If you want to output category-specific menus in specific template locations, you would be better off to output your category-specific menu conditionally, with a fallback to a custom nav menu. (Or, better yet: conditionally output a user-assigned custom nav menu, with a fallback to your category menu.)

For example:

```
<div id="cat-menu">
<?php
// if the user has assigned a menu, use it
if ( has_nav_menu( 'cat-menu' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'cat-menu'
    ) );
}
// otherwise, if this is a category archive index page,
// output a category menu
else if ( is_category() ) {
    // output a list of categories
}
?>
</div>
```

That said, your issue is mainly a PHP/syntax problem. You need to build an array of menu locations, and then pass that built array to the register function.

```
// Base menu locations
$menu_locations = array(
    'primary' => 'Main Navigation',
    'secondary' => 'Footer Navigation'
);

// Get categories
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();

// Loop through them
foreach( $category_ids as $cat_id ) {
    // Get the Category object
    $cat_obj = get_category( $cat_id );

    // Get the Category Slug
    $cat_slug = $cat_obj->slug;

    // Concatenate it as a menu slug
    $menu_slug = $cat_slug . '-menu';

    // Get the Category Name
    $cat_name = $cat_obj->name;

    // Concatenate it as a menu name
    $menu_name = $cat_name . ' Menu';

    // Now add it to the array of menu locations
    $menu_locations[$menu_slug] = $menu_name;
}

// Now register
register_nav_menus( $menu_locations );
```

Answer (score 1):

From using var_dump($arr) it looked like it was still spitting out an array that WordPress didn't know what to do with. Same with $cat_name. You have to tell WordPress, for each id in that array that comes from $category_ids (that you're now calling $cat_id for the individual ids), you want to get each of their names as well as register a menu for each.

```
<?php 
$category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
foreach($category_ids as $cat_id):
    $catName = get_cat_name( $cat_id );
    register_nav_menu($cat_id, $catName);
endforeach;
?>
```

I'm not sure if there is a cleaner solution so that you don't have to register_nav_menu multiple times, but this appears to work. Hope it helps.

Also if you need more explanation on arrays, [this course on tutsplus](https://tutsplus.com/course/php-fundamentals/) helped me a lot!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you wanted to assign already created menus to this. I wrote it so that you assign them from your dashboard and it'll have the dropdown areas for each category menu.